# jQuery Cycle.js error next is undefined

Tags: jquery, joomla

I've used cycle on loads of projects but this one has really thrown me.  I'm working on a site with cycle, it works fine in my flat mockup here: http://www.meltingpotdesign.co.uk/momo5/

and now im turning it into a Joomla 1.5 template and it is throwing an error `next is undefined` - although it still works: http://www.meltingpotdesign.co.uk/momosaics/

Why?  I've tried disabling Mootools and that makes no difference so it doesn't seem to be a library clash.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the cycle plugin up to date? http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js has a date of 2012 April.

Comment: Superstar, thanks, that's solved it!